# ajax request error "access control allow origin"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to successfully get a callback but i keep running into an error that states "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." this is my javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
  var userDate = $("#userDate").val();
  var bitcoinApiUrl = "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json";
  var bitcoinApiParams = {
    method:"currency"
  }
  // bitcoinApiUrl += "&currency" + userDate;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    AccessControlAllowCredentials: true,
    // AccessControlAllowOrigin:
    url: bitcoinApiUrl,
    success: function(response) {
    }
  });

  });
});
```

Comment: Is the error message unclear, or what is your question?

Comment: you are getting CORS problem, error says it all, your host server needs to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with allowed hosts that you can make request to

Comment: I'm asking how to fix it , from what i looked at i need to setup a server but is that the only way ? @FelixKling

Comment: yes, you need to setup a server - and be sure to cache the result so you  **Don't query more often than once every 15 minutes!**

Comment: If you can deal with JSON in return, then try using JSONP (note the P at the end) for speaking between domains  [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)